# Can we define the spin coherent state for spin half operator $\vec{S}$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, coherent-states

Here I meet two kinds of definitions for the spin coherent state:

1. $\vec{\widehat{S}}|\vec{n}\rangle=S\vec{n}|\vec{n}\rangle$ (in my quantum field theory course);
2. $\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\widehat{S}}|\vec{n}\rangle = S|\vec{n}\rangle$ (in Wen xiaogang's book).

where $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector in $2D$ space.

Are they equivalent?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to answer this question until you define $\vert \vec n\rangle$.

Comment: $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector in 2D space.

Comment: Then you have a one-particle system and $\vert\vec n\rangle$ is just a spin eigenstate.  All one-particle spin eigenstates are coherent as they are trivially displaced spin-up states, i.e $\vert\vec n\rangle = R(\omega)\vert \uparrow\rangle$ for some $R(\omega)\in SU(2)$.